# Match a character exactly once with regex

Tags: java, regex

How can I match a character exactly once with a regex in Java? Let's say I want to look for strings which contain exactly one time the digit 3, and it doesn't matter where it is.

I tried to do this with ".*3{1}.*" but obviously this will also match "330" as I specified with the period that I don't care what character it is. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you put some example, to passed or not passed ?

Answer (score 6):

```
^[^3]*3[^3]*$
```

Match (not three), then three, then (not three).

Edit: Adding `^` and `$` at beginning and end. This will force the regex to match the whole line. Thanks @Bobbyrogers and @Mindastic

Comment: This won't check the string as a whole and will match to the first 3 in his example "330". If you want to check to see if a whole string only contains a single 3, you need to specify that using `^` and `$`.

Comment: I think your regexp is missing something. It should be ^[^3]*3[^3]*$  because if not, it will match 4444344443, for example.

Comment: @Mindastic: It depends on the API. `String.matches()` in Java forces the pattern to match the whole string, so anchors are not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

A non-regex solution:

```
int index = s.indexOf('3');
boolean unique = index != -1 && index == s.lastIndexOf('3');
```

Basically the character is unique if the first and last occurrences are at the same place and exist in the string (not -1).